# Java Swing menuItem -> popup with inputs

Tags: java, swing

So how can I make that when I press a JmenuItem it pops up a window where Iwould have to insert, for example, a date and select from a couple of check boxes? Do I make this "pop up" a new Jframe?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Use a JOptionPane or JDialog. Don't think that JOptionPanes are toy windows -- they're not, as they can hold and display complex GUI's within them if need be.

Comment: Also look at: [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636)